# Split and search comma separated column in Presto (AWS Athena)

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, concatenation, presto, amazon-athena

I have the following table `my_table`, where both the columns are strings-

```
+------------+-------------+
|     user_id|        code |
+------------+-------------+
|      ABC123|  yyy,123,333|
|        John|  xxx,USA,555|
|      qwerty|  55A,AUS,666|
|      Thomas|  zzz,666,678|
+------------+-------------+
```

I need to get all the `user_id` that have either of `yyy` or `666` in their `code` column value. I've tested the following query on online MySQL simulations where it **works fine**, but it won't work in AWS Athena-

```
SELECT user_id FROM my_table WHERE CONCAT(",", code, ",") REGEXP ",(yyy|666),";
```

The result should be-

```
+------------+
|     user_id|
+------------+
|      ABC123|
|      qwerty|
|      Thomas|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`regexp_like`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/regexp.html#regexp_like):

```
WHERE regexp_like(code, '(^|,)(xxx|yyy)(,|$)')
```

```sql
presto:default> SELECT regexp_like('yyy,123,333', '(^|,)(xxx|yyy)(,|$)');
 _col0
-------
 true
(1 row)
```

(tested in Presto 322, will work in Athena too)

For "more obviously correct" approach, I'd recommend using [`split`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/string.html#split) + [`contains`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#contains), although this might be less performant.

Comment: just to confirm, should my query be `SELECT user_id FROM my_table WHERE regexp_like(code, '(^|,)(yyy|666)(,|$)');` ?

Comment: works great, thanks. Also, does `regexp_like` work faster than split + contains?

Comment: I would assume so. If your query performance is IO dominated, it won't be any faster though.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a built-in function:

```
select t.*
from t
where find_in_set('666', code) > 0 or find_in_set('yyy', code) > 0;
```

Although this function is available, it is strongly recommended that you fix your data model and NOT store lists in strings.  That is not the SQLish way to store things.

Comment: i actually know this approach, but what if i want to do a `find_in_set` for 50 values :( Also, I know this column shouldn't be a string, but this can't be changed as it's not in my hands

Comment: @kev . . . Then you have 50 comparisons.

Comment: you're right, it's just that the query gets huge. Also I apologize for not being clear in the beginning, but while your query works fine in MySQL - just like the one in my question - it doesn't work in Presto.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regexp_like()** function to get the columns validating the above condition . This will return  a boolean value for the corresponding column . You can then use WHERE clause to filter out the result.

**FINAL QUERY:**

```
WITH dataset AS (
     SELECT 
       user_id,
       regexp_like(code, '(^|,)(666|yyy)(,|$)') AS code 
       FROM my_table
)
SELECT user_id from dataset where code=true
```